# How to extract Annotations in PDFTron in Android and save to db?

Tags: android, pdftron

I'm trying to get all the Annotations eg: INK and save to the db from Android.

I have looked thru the PDFTron examples particularly ElementReaderAdvTest. I can follow where it process Element.e_path and prints out the path.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/kt/ElementReaderAdvTest?platforms=android

How do I save each path data and later on I want to convert the path data to svg.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF ISO standard defines an annotation data interchange format called FDF. FDF is a PDF file with no pages, and just annotations and/or form field values.

To just extract the annotations use the following

```
pdfviewctrl.docLockRead();
FDFDoc fdf = pdfviewctrl.getDoc().fdfExtract(PDFDoc.e_annots_only);
pdfviewctrl.docUnlockRead();
```

You can then save the FDF file as binary/pdf data in whatever storage you want. You do not have to save the annotated PDF, you can at anytime later on merge back.

```
doc.fdfMerge(fdf);
```

You would not go into the ElementReader sample code, that is too low level for what you want, and just FDFMerge and FDFExtract are probably all you need.